# Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object after magento migration

Tags: magento-1.9, product, upgrade, migration, magento-1.5

I have migrated a magento store from 1.5 to 1.9 on my local server.(First migrated 1.5 to 1.6.2 then 1.6.2 to 1.9.1)

Now whenever i try to edit or add a new product following fatal error occurs.

**Images :** Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.

**Fatal error:** `Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in /var/www/html/monster_19/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php on line 366`

This error also occurs on 1.6.2 staging version. Tried database repair tool also but problem still persist . And i don't want to hack into core. Please give solution.

Comment: I have the exact same error, which extension did you have to upload to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before trying anything, clear the cache. That might not help, but do it anyway.

The error is cause by this:

```
$this->_frontend = Mage::getModel($this->getFrontendModel())
            ->setAttribute($this);
```

this means `Mage::getModel($this->getFrontendModel())` returns `null` (or `false`).
This can be caused by an attribute that has the field `frontend_model` set to something like `[module]/something_here`  but the class `[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Something_Here` does not exist.
You can identify the attribute by adding the following code above the line I mentioned:

```
$model = Mage::getModel($this->getFrontendModel());
if (!$model) {
    echo $this->getAttributeCode();exit;
}
```

You should see the attribute code in your page.
Then look in the `eav_attribute` table for this attribute and see if something is wrong with it. If you think the attribute is not needed anymore just delete it.

Comment: Thanks. I was an idiot...forgot to upload an existing extension.
Working fine now.

Comment: I have the same error, which page should I add the code you suggest to see the attribute code?

Answer (score 2):

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on boolean in E:\wamp64\www\magento19_sampledata\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Abstract.php on line 366
```

in my case,

it was due to, disabled local modules by `<disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>`

after enabling the local modules,  it works fine.